# odoo ecommerce grid view and list view toggle instead of replace

Tags: odoo, odoo-website

In odoo website we can switch views from grid to list view for products list. But when the view is turned on from customize section it replaces the product grid view. Following is the line which replaces the grid view to list view:

```
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='products_grid']//table" position="replace">
        <t t-foreach="products" t-as="product">
            <div class="oe_product oe_list oe_product_cart" t-att-data-publish="product.website_published and 'on' or 'off'">
                <t t-call="website_sale.products_item">
                    <t t-set="show_publish" t-value="True" />
                </t>
            </div>
        </t>
    </xpath>
```

How to have both views for the products grid and list so that we can toggle views?

I can inherit the views and put both of them on the new template of custom module. Like :

```
                        <!--- THE GRID VIEW -->                            
                         <table width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr t-ignore="true">
                                    <td t-foreach="range(0,rows)" t-as="row" t-attf-width="#{100/rows}%"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr t-foreach="bins" t-as="tr_product">
                                    <t t-foreach="tr_product" t-as="td_product">
                                        <t t-if="td_product">
                                            <t t-set="product" t-value="td_product['product']" />
                                            <td t-att-colspan="td_product['x'] != 1 and td_product['x']" t-att-rowspan="td_product['y'] != 1 and td_product['y']" t-attf-class="oe_product oe_grid oe-height-#{td_product['y']*2} #{ td_product['class'] }">
                                                <div class="oe_product_cart" t-att-data-publish="product.website_published and 'on' or 'off'">
                                                    <t t-set="product_image_big" t-value="td_product['x']+td_product['y'] &gt; 2" />
                                                    <t t-call="website_sale.products_item" />
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </t>
                                        <td t-if="not td_product" class="oe-height-2" />
                                    </t>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                      <!--- THE LIST VIEW -->
                      <t t-foreach="products" t-as="product">
                         <div class="oe_product oe_list oe_product_cart" t-att-data-publish="product.website_published and 'on' or 'off'">
                            <t t-call="website_sale.products_item">
                               <t t-set="show_publish" t-value="True" />
                            </t>
                         </div>
                      </t>
```

**Now, how can I implement the toggle view for this?**